# How can redux - a global data layer in React app - be a good practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

If having global variables in the projects is generally not the best practice in programming, how can Redux - a global data layer - be a good idea?

The only thing that comes to my mind is that the immutability of a state is somehow helping Redux. However, all the problems like security issues (something accessible from everywhere), and visibility (corrupting data from many places) remain.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the concept of global variables and a global data layer. the store is not necessarily available as a global variable

Comment: Additionally, a front end is never really secure on its own, as anyone with the knowhow can open up the devtools and examine variable values.  So as @Yinhai mentioned, security needs to be managed with authentication and backend protections

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a `best practice` for not having global variables afaik.
It seems like developer all have their own opinions about it.

Global state management tools like redux just provide you a way to handle "temporary" data across the application preferably frontend while user is using your app/program. For instance, you can avoid to request same large amount of data repeatedly, as well as keeping the frontend data consistency in many cases.

They are not built for security safe. Even so, you should not rely on that.  Security issue is a separated problem since you have your backend to validate the data, the authentication to keep the consistency/safety between database/backend and frontend/client side.

By the end it all depends on what kinds of application you are currently building on.

Don't limit yourself into particular programming ideology.